# Is it possible to access .py file from another folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to access some functions form `create_database.py` from my `app.py` file. Is this possible?

This is structure of my folder:

```
application
├── database
│   └── create_database.py
└── microservice
    └── app.py
```

I was looking for solution and only found two codes that could help me but they didn't work for me.

1. `sys.path.append('path/to/folder')` and than `import create_database.py`. If i got this right it should work with full path but I need to be able to work with relative path since this app is going to be dockerized on server.
2. `from database.create_database import User` this throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'` here I also tried to create empty `__init__.py` in **database** folder but that also didn't help.

Comment: If app.py is used as a script (`python app.py`), try moving it up one level instead of having it inside `microservice`. Or run app.py as a module (from the `application` directory), via `python -m microservice.app`. Getting imports right can sometimes be a bit tricky. Your issue seems similar to the problem that prompted this popular question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/407651.

Comment: @mzjn I was trying to avoid it but eventually I found out that this is probably the only option. But it took some time to rethink whole structure of files because it's way more complicated than the example. But moving `app.py` one level up seems like only possible option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the empty `__init__.py` file:

```
from .create_database import User
__all__ = ["User"]
```

Then you should be able to import *User* in your current file as such:

```
from .database import User
```

I hope this helped. For clarification *`app.py`* is only ran from its directory right? Its not called in another script at different location.

Comment: So I tried it but it still throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'`. The _app.py_ just stores my functions they are called from file where are my API endpoints described. But I tried to run that function in the same file where it is declared but it still throws that same error.

Answer (score -1):

The following code to perform a relative system path change will work when `python app.py` is called from the `microservice` folder.

```
import sys

# Import create_database function from ./../database/create_database.py
# Since this is the root of the project, accessing other modules will be more straightforward.
sys.path.append('./../')

from database.create_database import User
```

Comment: Never mess with `sys.path` unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing, especially don't put a relative path there like here.